# Java openCV 3.0 VideoCapture rtsp stream from Foscam FI9805W

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm trying to get a videostream vom an ip cam with opencv 3.0 in java.
Everything works fine if i look for my webcam with this code:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
```

but with the RTSP Stream I get an error.
What I found was that it should work to get a RTSP Stream like this:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("rtsp://test:test@192.168.1.76:88/videoMain");
```

User: test

Password: test

I am using a Foscam FI9805W. On this website are possible ways to connect but nothings works (http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=foscam)

I only can connect via VLC Player and the rtsp://test:test@192.168.1.76:88/videoMain.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or could give me a hint where to search? I'm out of ideas.
Or does anyone know a better way to access a RTSP stream with java?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it with vlcj

the code is from here:
http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/direct-rendering