# RTSP stream with OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I am working on a simple motion detection project. I would like my video input to originate from a Sony network camera, thus I am trying to capture an RTSP stream.

I am doing this at the moment:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@172.23.1.9/media/video1");
```

and I open the camera stream like this:

```
camera.open("rtsp://admin:admin@172.23.1.9/media/video1");
```

The problem I am facing is when is try to check whether the stream has indeed opened up.

Using the isOpened() method always returns false.

I have tried to search online for a solution to this but so far I have not managed to find any.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055704/java-opencv-3-0-videocapture-rtsp-stream-from-foscam-fi9805w

Comment: Have you solved the issue? @Aris

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not have any spare to deal with this as of yes (this was a side project of mine).

If I get around fixing it, I will post an answer.